# How to find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{1}^{n}x^{-n}dx$?

Tags: calculus

How to evaluate the following limit?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{x^{n}}dx.$$

Comment: Applying [Lebesgue's monotone convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem), one obtains the limit equals 0.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_{1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{x^{n}}dx = \frac{n^{1-n}}{1-n}-\frac1{1-n} \to 0$$

Comment: I am able to reach this step, but failed to obtain the limit. Is there any faster way to solve this?

Comment: $\frac{n^{1-n}}{1-n} = \frac{1}{(1-n)n^{n-1}}$. Now in both fractions the numerator is $1$ and the denominator $\to \infty$.

Comment: The second term is obviously equals to 0. To obtain the limit of the first term, am I supposed to use the L'Hospital's rule?

Comment: It is simple! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

1. perform the integration.
2. show the integral is between $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n-1}$ for $n\ge 2$.
3. find the limit of $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n-1}$

Answer (score 0):

First integrate, and then get the limit.